# Issues Installing Avira Antivirus

Tags: windows-xp, installation, avira

When I try to install Avira Free Antivirus in my Windows XP every time some extraction process starts and then this process disappears. I am not able to download this Antivirus. What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, please? Which steps are you taking, exactly, and where does it fail?

Comment: I just double clicked the .exe file, some extraction process started after that this process disappeared and no installation wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your file has been corrupted. Download it again [from the website](http://www.avira.com/en/index).

1. Make sure you don't have any other third-party antivirus software installed. If so, then uninstall them.
2. Please make sure that you've installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) — if not, install it and reboot the computer and then install Avira.
3. And also run [this removal tool](http://www.avira.com/en/support-download-avira-antivir-removal-tool/product/) and then freshly install it

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to download OR install this Antivirus?
If you already downloaded it correctly, try to extract/check the installation setup file with 7-zip. (7-zip is able to open and extract some .exe files).

The setup file you downloaded may be corrupted.

Comment: I downloaded an .exe from Avira's site itself.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the downloaded file was probably corrupted. You could try to download it again, and if the problem persists, try to do it from another computer. Ideally, you could check the checksum of the downloaded file.